# To find Index of Multidimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created a multidimensional array in JavaScript and I want to find the exact index of specific value. That value will be user input.

```
var array = [];
var k = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  array[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    k = k + 1
    array[i].push(k);
  }
}
var index = array.indexOf(`**"What to insert here???"**`);
```

Comment: You have to iterate elements to find nested value.

Comment: What's `k`? Right now, the code above causes an error, because you try to read the value of `k`, but `k` isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: t-j-crowder: k is a global variable which is set to 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: What did you try? How/why didn't they work? Please review topics in the the SO help section, linked to at the top of every page for details on required info for valid questions on SO.

Comment: @SherylHohman - I asked this on Apr 19, 2013, I wonder what triggered this comment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wao20/Lct1de56/)

```js
/**
 * Index of Multidimensional Array
 * @param arr {!Array} - the input array
 * @param k {object} - the value to search
 * @return {Array} 
 */
function getIndexOfK(arr, k) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var index = arr[i].indexOf(k);
    if (index > -1) {
      return [i, index];
    }
  }
}

// Generate Sample Data
var k = 0;
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  array[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    k = k + 1;
    array[i].push(k);
  }
}
var needle = 130;
var result = getIndexOfK(array, needle);
console.log('The value #' + needle + ' is located at array[' + result[0] + '][' + result[1] + '].');
```

Answer (score 2):

this example seems to work well also with IRREGULAR multidimentional array:

```
function findIndex(valueToSearch, theArray, currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == undefined) currentIndex = '';
        if(Array.isArray(theArray)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
                if(Array.isArray(theArray[i])) {
                    newIndex = findIndex(valueToSearch, theArray[i], currentIndex + i + ',');
                    if (newIndex) return newIndex;
               } else if (theArray[i] == valueToSearch) {
                   return currentIndex + i;
               }
            }
    } else if (theArray == valueToSearch) {
        return currentIndex + i;
    }
    return false;
}

var a = new Array();
a[0] = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
a[1] = 'ciao';
a[2] = new Array(new Array(6,7),new Array(8,9),10);

var specificIndex = findIndex('10', a);
```

i wrote this speedly so everyone is invited to improve this function!

p.s. now the function returns a STRING value with all indexes separated by comma, you can simply edit it to returns an object

Comment: There is WIP for [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 1):

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9xh8j/)

```
function indexOf2d(arr, val) {
    var index = [-1, -1];

    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
        return index;
    }

    arr.some(function (sub, posX) {
        if (!Array.isArray(sub)) {
            return false;
        }

        var posY = sub.indexOf(val);

        if (posY !== -1) {
            index[0] = posX;
            index[1] = posY;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    return index;
}

console.log(indexOf2d(array, 50));
```

Answer (score 0):

My code does like a PROCV in MS Excel... and identifies the Index searching only in the first column. Maybe help you (or others).

```
var convertToRoman = function (valueLimitTen) {   
  var convertTable = [  [1, "I"],
                        [2, "II"],
                        [3, "III"],
                        [4, "IV"],
                        [5, "V"],
                        [6, "VI"],
                        [7, "VII"],
                        [8, "VIII"],
                        [9, "IV"],
                        [10, "X"],
                      ];

  var myIndex;  
  for(var i in convertTable){
    if(convertTable[i][0] == valueLimitTen){
      myIndex = i;      
      return convertTable[i][1];      
    }  
  }  
}

console.log(convertToRoman(2)); //Result II
console.log(convertToRoman(10)); //Result X
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 has made this considerably easier.

```
function findIndexOfNestedArray(nestedArray, searchArray) {
  return searchArray.findIndex(item => {
    return item.length === nestedArray.length
    && item.every((a, i) => a === nestedArray[i])
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple way:

```
[1,2] === [1,2] // > false
JSON.stringify([1,2]) === JSON.stringify([1,2]) // > true
```

So we could do something like:

```
arrays.findIndex(array => JSON.stringify(array)  === JSON.stringify(arrayToCompare))
```

Answer (score 0):

With findIndex() and indexOf() you can do it in 2 lines:

```
const valueToSearch = "whatever";
let row = yourArray.findIndex((elem)=>elem.includes(valueToSearch));
let column = yourArray[row].indexOf(valueToSearch);
```