# find index of object inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array of objects which generated from list of an items from HTML, I faced a problem in dealing with the array to get index of item and the length of the array, always gets Zero.

I want both data-id and value (list 1,2,3 ..).

**HTML Code**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li data-id="l1">list 1</li>
    <li data-id="l2">list 2</li>
    <li data-id="l3">list 3</li>
    <li data-id="l4">list 4</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

**JS Code**

```
var arr = new Array();

$('.list li').each(function(){
    var lid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var lval = $(this).html();
    arr[lid] = lval;
});

$('p').html('array length = ' + arr.length + ' & index of list 1 is ' + arr.indexOf('l1'));
```

I'm new in javascript and jQuery i don't know if i have errors with syntax . check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8794w7j4/) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code its working.

```
var arr ={};

$('.list li').each(function(){    
    arr[$(this).attr('data-id')]=$(this).html();
});

function find(ar, val){
var i=0;
$.each(ar, function (key, data) {
      if(data==val)
      {
         return false;
      }
    i++;
});
    return i;
};
$('p').html('array length = ' + Object.keys(arr).length  + ' & index of list 1 is '+find(arr, "list 2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `arr.push(lval);` instead:

You are trying to use `l1` as the index where you want to add your data but `l1` is a string and the index must be a number. `.push()` will add the given element as the last element in the given array, probably more what you are looking for.

Since you want both the `data-id` and the element's `html`, create a multidimensional array by doing `arr.push( [lid, lval] )`

```js
var arr = new Array();

$('.list li').each(function(){
    var lid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var lval = $(this).html();
    arr.push( [lid, lval] );
});

$('p').html('array length = ' + arr.length + ' & index of list 1 is ' + getIndexOfK(arr, 'l1'));


// access values like 
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  
  $('#myDiv').append( 'this element\'s data-id= '+ arr[i][0] +'------ this element\'s html= ' + arr[i][1]+'<br>' );
}






// function to get index of given element in a multidemensional array
// you may not actually need this, it was jsut to get your idex 
// credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102263/to-find-index-of-multidimensional-array-in-javascript
function getIndexOfK(arr, k){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        var index = arr[i].indexOf(k);
        if (index > -1){
            return [i, index];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
  margin-top:50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li data-id="l1">list 1</li>
    <li data-id="l2">list 2</li>
    <li data-id="l3">list 3</li>
    <li data-id="l4">list 4</li>
</ul>
<p></p>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: @Alexander what do you mean?

Comment: but what if i need the key or id is the value of data-id ! to use it later as an identify

Comment: so you need both the data-id and the html values?

Answer (score 0):

You are using your new Array as an object. In Javascript arrays only have numeric indexes. After your loop finishes, you basically have an object.That's why length returns 0.

Change your code to:

```
var arr = new Array();
```

var counter = 0;

```
$('.list li').each(function(){
    var lid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var lval = $(this).html();
    arr[lid] = lval;
    counter++;
});

$('p').html('array length = ' + counter + ' & index of list 1 is l1');
```

And you'll know what I mean. The index already is 'l1', there is no numeric part.

EDIT:

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24yb640s/) of the changed code.
You think you get something like this:

```
 ['list 1','list 2','list 3','list 4']
```

but you actually get something like this:

{
'l1':'list 1',
'l2':'list 2',
'l3':'list 3',
'l4':'list 4'
}

Answer (score 0):

try this

Using `push` you can add elements to Array and in `indexOf` you need to Pass `lid` to Your Array

```
var arr = new Array();

$('.list li').each(function(){
    var lid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var lval = $(this).html();
    arr.push(lid);
});

$('p').html('array length = ' + arr.length + 
' & index of list 1 is ' + arr.indexOf('l1'));
```

**JS Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/0vfgnoav/

Comment: what about value of 'l1' ?

Comment: @user3003810 check the fiddle

Comment: the list value not included in the array, for example if I write arr[0] or arr['l1'], are the same, it should type 'list 1' !. @Ganesh_Devlekar

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var arr = new array();

var counter =0;
$('.list li').each(function(){
    var dataid= $(this).attr('data-id');
    var getvalue = $(this).html();
    arr[dataid] = getvalue ;
    counter++;
});

$('p').html('array length = ' + counter + ' & index of list 1 is l1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8794w7j4/)

```
   var arr = new Array();
   var i = 0;
   $('.list li').each(function(){
      var lid = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var lval = $(this).html();
      arr[i] = lval;
      i++;
   });

  $('p').html('array length = ' + arr.length + ' & index of list 1 is ' + arr.indexOf('list 1'));
```