# How to find the index value of an two dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `2D array` which looks like this:

```
var numbers=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,2,3,5,5],[9,8,3,4,9]]
```

How to find the index value  of the above two dimensional array?

Comment: What is the "index value"?

Comment: `array[0][1]` would return "2" from the first "block" in the array.
Why and how do you want to return an index?

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102263/to-find-index-of-multidimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
var searchItem=2;
numbers.forEach(function(parentItem,parentIndex){
  parentItem.forEach(function(childItem,childIndex){
     if(childItem===searchItem){
        console.log(parentIndex);
        console.log(childIndex);            
     }     
 })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findInArr(arr, elm) {
    var occ = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            if(arr[i][j] == elm)
                occ.push(i+"*"+j);
    return occ;
}
```

Test:

```
var numbers = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,2,3,5,5],[9,8,3,4,9]];
var x = findInArr(numbers, 4);
console.log("found " + x.length + " occurences: " + x);
```

> found 2 occurences: 0*3,2*3