# how to get an index of an array if the checked value is in the nested array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
const myArray = [ [ false ], [ true ], [ false ] ]
```

i want to get index of an element that has value == true from array above.

so because the `true` from array above is in the second element, then I want to get `1` as the index result

how to do that ?

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work? do you have only one array with `true`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To find Index of Multidimensional Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102263/to-find-index-of-multidimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need add filter for this,

```
const myArray = [ [ false ], [ true ], [ false ] ] 

let result = myArray.filter(function(value) {
    return value[0]=== true;
});
```

Comment: That returns a filtered array, not the index of the array with a true value.

Answer (score 1):

```
const arrays = [ [ false ], [ true ], [ false ] ] 

const index = [].concat.apply([], arrays).findIndex(value => value === true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const idx = myArray.findIndex(i => i[0]);
```

Comment: Post answer with only code is not good, please explains always your answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The code is so simple I would think it self explanatory, noting that the other answers either offer no explanation, or a rather redundant one-liner. IMO this is still the best answer. The accepted answer is plain wrong, and the other upvoted answer uses a hard to read array flattening technique that *does* need explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop on your array with map method

```js
const arr = [ [ false ], [ true ], [ false ] ] 

arr.map((item, index) => {

if (item[0]) {
  console.log(index)
}

})
```

Comment: `map` returns a new array. if this is not used later, it makes no sense.